# Using ng-style to set background if value doesn't match

Tags: javascript, css, json, angularjs

Hello everyone I have a ng-repeat for a ul, making li for each item.

In the json I have a value I want to highlight if doesn't match a predefined string like this:

```
ng-style="{'background-color':(json.string!=='NO_MATCH'?'yellow')}
```

This is the full ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="json in json" ng-style="{'background-color':(json.string!=='NO_MATCH'?'yellow')}>{{ json.title }} - {{ json.display }}</li>
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong here?

Comment: One thought I have is the item in the array "json.string" is not displayed does this matter?

Comment: ng-style="{'background-color: yellow;': json.string!=='NO_MATCH'}"

Comment: ng-style="{'background-color: yellow;': json.string!=='NO_MATCH'}"

Comment: @MatthewBrianSheets Can you show your `controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ngClass** instead **ngStyle**. Because **ngStyle** added in inline style of the li

In css

```
.yellow {
  background-color : yellow
}
```

In html

```
<li ng-repeat="json in json" ng-class="{'yellow' : json.string !== 'NO_MATCH'}">{{ json.title }} - {{ json.display }}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
ng-style="{'background-color: yellow;': json.string!=='NO_MATCH'}"
```